# How can a user provide his/her current location in Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In 2019 Facebook announced that it has deprecated location quick reply on Messenger. In the announcement it said

> While we are sunsetting the existing version of Share Location, in the
>   coming months we will be introducing new ways for people to
>   communicate their location to businesses in more valuable ways.

What are the new ways for people to communicate their location (using Messenger) to businesses so that more relevant information can be given back to customers ?

Comment: i guess they did not introduce them yet

Comment: The sentence right before what you just quoted there reads, _“We recommend businesses ask for zip code and address information within the thread.”_ - so that’s probably your way to go, until they announce something new.

Comment: @CBroe I don't know why they suggested Zip Code. As you can imagine Zip Codes vary from Country to Country unlike longitude and latitude which was possible with Location quick reply. It is difficult to change implementation for each Country using Zip Code.

Comment: Why wouldn’t they suggest it, so far we don’t even know what you’d want this info for, or what level of detail you’d need. There’s probably loads of applications, for which something like, “hey I am in country X, and my post code is Y” would be initially sufficient information.

Comment: If you need “exact” coordinates, sending the user to an external URL, where you use the Geolocation API, might be an alternative. (Assuming that works inside a Webview, didn’t check.) To be able to connect the info that page sends back to your server (outside of messenger), you could pass some sort of identifier, like something based on the user ID you got inside messenger.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, yeah I want to help the users with some recommendations based on their exact coordinates. For now, I am planning to ask and send their address to Geo location API like Google's to fetch their coordinates.. I think it is not as efficient as getting coordinates from location quick reply. I wasn't sure if there is any better way that Facebook has provided recently.